# Check list for similar items

Tags: python, list

Given the following list

```
simple_list = ['abcX1', 'def', 'abc', 'abcX2', 'abcY', 'defX1', 'efg', 'fgh']
```

How can I delete items, which start the same but do not have a suffix.

Example:

- Of `'abcX1', 'abc, 'abcX2', 'abcY'` I only want to keep `'abcX1', 'abcX2', 'abcY'`
- Of `'def', 'defX1'` I want to keep `'defX1'`
- Of `'efg', 'fgh'` I want to keep both, as they do not have a counterpart with a suffix

My thoughts:

```
for i in simple_list:
   for j in simple_list:
      Here I am stuck
```

Furthermore, my attempt does not seem very pythonic. So suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with some of your *actual* code you have tried which doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any fixed length (eg 3) of the elements that must be deleted or they can be of any length even 1?

Comment: You just need to replace `delete as described above` with actual code which does that.

Comment: Depends a bit on the size of your list, if it is relatively small just use the solution from goodvibration. There are faster algorithms by building a tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For short lists, you can just use a nested list comprehension with `any`, checking whether the current element is a prefix of any other element (except itself).

```
lst = ['abcX1', 'def', 'abc', 'abcX2', 'abcY', 'defX1', 'efg', 'fgh']

res = [x for x in lst if not any(x != y and y.startswith(x) for y in lst)]
```

If the list contains duplicate elements, all the duplicates will be kept; in this case, you should compare indices instead of the elements themselves, or create a set from the elements first.)

Note, however, that this will have quadratic complexity, i.e. O(n²), which may be prohibitive for longer lists. Better (but also a bit more complicated) would be to create a Trie, or prefix tree, from all the words, and then use only the leafs of that tree.

```
tree = {}
for w in lst:
    t = tree
    for c in w:
        t = t.setdefault(c, {})

def leafs(t, p=""):
    return [x for k in t for x in leafs(t[k], p+k)] if t else [p]

res = list(leafs(tree))
```

The complexity for creating the tree and getting the leafs should be O(n*k), with n being the number of words and k the avg. number of letters in each word.<sup>1</sup>

Another way, a bit simpler: Note that if `x` is a prefix of `y`, then `x` will be sorted *right before* `y`, so you can sort the list and then just compare consecutive values. The complexity for this will be O(n logn) for sorting and then O(n) for filtering.

```
srt = sorted(lst)
res = [x for i, x in enumerate(srt)
         if i == len(srt) - 1 or not srt[i+1].startswith(x)]
```

Both the tree and sorting-approach may scramble the order of elements in the result. If you want the elements in their original order, you can create a `set` from the filtered elements and then do another pass over the original list, keeping the elements that are in the set. This will add another O(n):

```
res_set = set(res)
res = [x for x in lst if x in res_set]
```

Each way, the result `res` is `['abcX1', 'abcX2', 'abcY', 'defX1', 'efg', 'fgh']`. Also, they all will create a new, filtered list, but not modify the original.

---

I did some more timing analysis. For your list, as expected there is not too much of a difference. Interestingly, the prefix-tree is slowest, probably since the overhead of creating all those dictionaries beats the O(n²) on the short list. Sorting is fastest.

```
>>> %timeit test.simple(lst)
10000 loops, best of 5: 44.3 µs per loop
>>> %timeit test.prefixtree(lst)
10000 loops, best of 5: 51.6 µs per loop
>>> %timeit test.sorting(lst)
100000 loops, best of 5: 11.2 µs per loop
```

More importantly, on a list of 1000 words, the prefix-tree -- now *much* faster than the nested loop -- is still considerably slower than sorting, despite its lower complexity. My explanation for this is that the O(n logn) of the builtin `sorted` is implemented in fast C whereas the O(n) of the tree is still slow Python.

```
>>> %timeit test.simple(words)
1 loop, best of 5: 562 ms per loop
>>> %timeit test.prefixtree(words)
100 loops, best of 5: 8.42 ms per loop
>>> %timeit test.sorting(words)
1000 loops, best of 5: 1.23 ms per loop
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I added the k factor here as it is more obvious in this algorithm, but of course using `startswith` is also not O(1) but O([length of actual prefix])

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
filtered_list = [x for x in simple_list if not any([y.startswith(x) and y != x for y in simple_list])]
```

Comment: ```defX1``` will be kept but ```defX12``` will get deleted in this case